# How can I pass an array of variables from php to javascript?

Tags: javascript

I use this but cannot find solution.

```
drupal_add_js(
  array('YOURMODULE' => array(
    'testvar' => $testvar
  )),
  array('type' => 'setting')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the object **Drupal.settings** using Firebug.

Or insert the code into your a js file.

```
Drupal.behaviors.YOURMODULE = function (context) {
  alert(Drupal.settings.YOUMODULE.testvar);
}
```